# Typescript: How to access super. inside of callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to access a method from the extended class inside of an Callback:

```
Model.findOne( { _id: id }, function( err, rec ){
    super.handleFind( err, rec ); 
});
```

When I compile my Typescript I see following error:

```
error TS2660: 'super' can only be referenced in members of derived classes or object literal expressions.
```

When I then run the JavaScript, I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
```

If - before the Callback - I do something like let **fct = super.handleFind;** it seems to work, but **this** is undefined inside of handleFind() - and I need the **this** context.

Answer (score 2):

Assume `handleFile` is defined in the parent class, it will then be inherited by your subclass, unless you are overriding `handleFile` in your subclass and you want to use the implementation of `handleFile` from the superclass instead, then you can just call it using `this.handleFile`.

The second issue is that you are passing a `function() {...}` callback to `Model.findOne`, if you want to preserve the `this` context (make it point to the current instance of your subclass), use arrow function instead, so change your function to this

```
 // Use arrow function to make 'this' point to the current instance of the
 // enclosing class
Model.findOne( { _id: id }, ( err, rec ) => {
    super.handleFind( err, rec ); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Function.prototype.call()` to call the anonymous function passed to `.findOne()` with context set to `this` : `Model` `class`

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {}
  handleFind(err, rec) {
    console.log(err, rec)
  }
}

class Model extends Test {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  findOne(id, fn) {
    fn.call(this, id, "err")
  }
}

var model = new Model();

model.findOne({id: 123}, function(err, rec) {
  this.handleFind(err, rec)
});
```